Multiple tab selection with Org and Helm; TAB not behaving as expected
When adding tags to and entry while using org-mode, helm provides list of available candidate tags and narrows the list as I type, as expected.
However, I expect that hitting TAB will auto-complete with the selected tag in the list, and let me continue typing to add more tags.
Instead, TAB switches the mode line to "Select action" with a limited list of actions (screenshot below).
My guess is this is some additional functionality of Helm, but I don't quite understand it and it's not what I expect.
Are there customization options available that will let TAB auto-complete the selected tag in candidate list, instead of showing this actions list?
NOTE: I can hit ENTER to choose the selected candidate, but that prevents me from creating a list of tags (e.g. "todo:work").
Thank you! Relevant documentation links also welcome; I couldn't find anything related to "helm actions" when searching.

